# What is the TikZ equivalent for the following PSTricks code? Drawing a free fall diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, asymptote

I want to learn TikZ using "learn by example" approach because this way helps me to save time by skipping unnecessary concepts. I have made an example, it is a free fall diagram in PSTricks as follows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\def\LoadConstants{}
\newcommand\const[3][3]{%
    \edef\temporary{round(#3}%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname
        \expandafter{\temporary:#1)}%
        \edef\LoadConstants{\LoadConstants
            \noexpand\pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}}%
}


\const[1]{G}{9.8}
\const[1]{Tfinal}{2.0}
\def\y(#1){-G/2*#1^2}
\const[1]{Yfinal}{\y(Tfinal)}

\SpecialCoor
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](3.5,\Yfinal)
    \LoadConstants
    \psline(1.5,0)(1.5,\Yfinal)
    \multido{\n=0.0+0.5}{5}
    {
        \const[1]{Yt}{\y(\n)}%
        \rput[r](*1.25 {\y(\n)}){$\SI{\Yt}{\meter}$}
        \psline(1.4,\Yt)(1.6,\Yt)
        \rput[l](*1.75 {\y(\n)}){$t=\SI{\n}{\second}$}
        \pscircle*(*3.5 {\y(\n)}){5pt}
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I have a problem in evaluating algebraic expression and printing its value in TikZ. This is my attempt.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}


\def\G{9.8}
\def\Tfinal{2.0}
\def\y(#1){-\G/2*#1^2}
\def\Yfinal{\y(\Tfinal)}


\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (1.5,0) -- (1.5,\Yfinal);
    \foreach \n in {0.0,0.5,...,2.0}
    {
        \draw ({1.25},{\y(\n)}) node {$\SI{\y(\n)}{\meter}$};
        \draw ({1.4},{\y(\n)}) -- ({1.6},{\y(\n)});
        \draw ({1.75},{\y(\n)}) node {$t=\SI{\n}{\second}$};
        \draw[fill=black] ({3.5},{\y(\n)}) circle (5pt);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If TikZ can work without `fp` package then it will be interesting.

Comment: You need to evaluate the `\y(\n)` before printing it in `siunitx`, do this: `\def\Y(#1){\pgfmathparse{\y(#1)}\edef\yn{\pgfmathresult}}` and replace: `$\SI{\y(\n)}{\meter}$` by `\Y(#1)$\SI{\yn}{\meter}$`, note that the evaluation cannot be performed inside the `SI` macro (it does magic beyond belief).

Comment: @zeroth: OK. Thank you. I will delete my question shortly.

Comment: Could you please do not delete your question but post a correct solution - I would love to see it!

Comment: @partial81: OK. I will try applying zeroth's suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My suggestion. First it's not necessary to place the axe at 1.5. You can use 0 and if you need to add other objects then you can shift with a scope. I used `\sisetup` to get a light code. As you can see you can remove `\Yfinal`. The nodes tmp have the same width so it's possible to place the circle relatively to tmp.east. With this way it's possible to scale the picture. Personally I prefer `\node at (x,y)` instead of `\draw (x,y) node`.

**update**

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{round-integer-to-decimal,
         round-mode = places,
         round-precision = 1}% possible numprint
\begin{document}

% constants
\def\G{9.8}
\def\Tfinal{2.0}
\def\y(#1){-\G/2*#1^2}

\begin{tikzpicture}% [scale=.5] possible with the next code
    \draw (0,0) -- (0,{\y(\Tfinal)}); % you don't nedd to use \Yfinal
    \foreach \n in {0.0,0.5,...,\Tfinal}
    {       
     \draw (-0.1,{\y(\n)}) -- (0.1,{\y(\n)});
     \node[left] at (-0.25,{\y(\n)}) {\pgfmathparse{\y(\n)}\SI{\pgfmathresult}{\meter}};
     \node[right] (tmp) at (0.25,{\y(\n)}) {$t=\SI{\n}{\second}$};
     \fill ([xshift=.25 cm]tmp.east) circle (5pt);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Comments: No need to remove white spaces in `\sisetup`, use `\Tfinal` in `foreach`, no need to use `$$` in the **first** `\SI{}{}`. Thank you for answering.

Comment: @Karl'sstudents I agree with all your remarks !

Comment: @Karl'sstudents I disagree with the latter one. The spacing around `=` will be incorrect. (and `siunitx` does use math-mode in the most cases anyway).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: No problem because I did not say that in my previous comment. I have made the word "first" in bold face actually. And what Alain did is beyond my imagination. :-)

Comment: @Karl'sstudents And I meant the **latter** `\SI`. `;)` The comment is more directed towards Alain (but he gets notified anyway).

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Just in case if anyone would like to learn `Asymptote` as well, `freefall.asy`:

```
unitsize(5mm);
texpreamble("\usepackage["
  +"rm={oldstyle=true,tabular=true},"
  +"]{cfr-lm}");

real g=9.81;        // g constant
int n=5;            // number of time points
real dt=0.5;        // time interval
real tmax=(n-1)*dt; 

real h(real t){return t^2*g/2;};  // h(t) function

pair top=(0,0);
pair bottom=(0,-h(tmax));

real dx=0.6;                        // half of the tick width
guide tickMark=((-dx,0)--(dx,0));   // tick mark line

pair pos;
Label L;
real ballX=5;                       // x- coordinate of the ball
real ballR=0.5;                     // ball radius
path ball=scale(ballR)*unitcircle;  // the ball outline

pen startColor=darkblue;            
pen finalColor=orange;

pen ballColor(int i, int n){  // interpolates the color at i-th time reading
  return (n-1.0-i)/(n-1.0)*startColor+i/(n-1.0)*finalColor;
};

guide shadeScale=scale(0.6,1)*box((-dx,0),(dx,-h(tmax)));   // shade scale outline
axialshade(shadeScale,          // axial shading of the shade scale outline
  startColor+0.3*white, top,    // start color & position
  finalColor+0.3*white, bottom  // final color & position
);

transform toBallPos;
real t=0.0;

for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
  pos=(0,-h(t));
//  draw(shift(pos)*tickMark,white+1.6pt);
  draw(shift(pos)*tickMark,ballColor(i,n)+1.2pt);
  L=Label("$t=$"+format("%#5.1f",t)+"\,s");
  label(L,pos+(dx,0),E);
  label(((h(t)!=0)?"$-$":"")+format("%#7.2f",h(t))+"\,m",pos-(dx,0),W);
  toBallPos=shift(pos+(ballX,0));
  radialshade(toBallPos*ball,  // transform is applied by "*" on the left
    white,toBallPos*(0,0),0.07*ballR
   ,ballColor(i,n),toBallPos*(0,0),ballR); 
  t+=dt;
}
```

To get a standalone `freefall.pdf`, run `asy -f pdf freefall.asy`.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}

\def\G{9.8}
\def\Tfinal{2.0}
\def\y(#1){-\G/2*#1^2}
\pgfmathparse{\y(\Tfinal)}
\edef\Yfinal{\pgfmathresult}

\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (1.5,0) -- (1.5,\Yfinal);
    \foreach \n in {0.0,0.5,...,\Tfinal}
    {       
        \draw ({1.25},{\y(\n)}) node[anchor=east] {\pgfmathparse{\y(\n)}\FPeval\temp{round(\pgfmathresult:1)}$\SI{\temp}{\meter}$};
        \draw ({1.4},{\y(\n)}) -- ({1.6},{\y(\n)});
        \draw ({1.75},{\y(\n)}) node[anchor=west] {\pgfmathparse{\n}\FPeval\temp{round(\pgfmathresult:1)}$t=\SI{\temp}{\second}$};
        \draw[fill=black] ({3.5},{\y(\n)}) circle (5pt);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As  `SI[round-mode=places,round-precision=1]...` changes `0.0` to `0` and `\pgfmathprintnumberto[precision=1]{\pgfmathresult}{\temp}` produces a numerical format that is not compatible with `\SI` now I use `\FPeval` as a fallback.

Comment: There is a difference in positioning an object between PTricks and Tikz. `\rput[l](x,y){object}` stands for placing the left side of `object` at point `(x,y)` while `\draw (x,y) node[left] {object}` stands for placing `object` to the left side of point `(x,y)`. Confusing to a newbie!

Comment: Instead of `[left]` use `[anchor=west]` which is the `rput[l]` equivalent. :)

Comment: @Karl'sstudents `$\num[round-mode = places,round-precision = 1]{0.0}$` gives 0.0 and not 0 ?? Possible also `\sisetup{round-integer-to-decimal} $\num[round-mode = places]{0}$`

Comment: @zeroth `[anchor=west]` is equivalent to `[left]`! The advantage of the last syntax is to authorize `left=⟨offset⟩`.

Comment: @AlainMatthes `\node[anchor=west] {A};` is not the same as `\node[left] {A};` did I misunderstand you? But yes, the offset is very nice to achieve a certain distance from the point, but that was not my goal here. :)

Comment: @zeroth mistake for me I would like to write `east` and not `west`: `left=⟨offset⟩ (default 0pt)` does the same as `anchor=east` (pgfmanual). `\tikz \fill (0,0) circle (2pt) node[left] {left};` or  `\tikz \fill (0,0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east] {left};`

Comment: @AlainMatthes yes. Great, then we agree! :)

Comment: Thanks @Karl's students for not deleting your question, the answer and the discussion are really interesting and helpful!